# Using a javascript variable to set PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get variable from PHP to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415868/get-variable-from-php-to-javascript)
>   [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

I currently have this line of code:

```
displaystatus('CALLER IS: '+inCallingNum);
```

which is being used to display a message on the page saying (e.g.) CALLER IS: 01234 567890.

What I need to do now is set the value of the inCallingNum variable in a PHP variable $user_number. Is this possible?

I tried something like this, but didnt have any luck with it:

```
<?php $user_number ?> = inCallingNum;
```

Thanks for any help

Edit:

This is where inCallingNum is set:

```
inCallingNum = inCallingNum.slice(inCallingNum.lastIndexOf(",")+1, inCallingNum.length);
```

Edit 2:

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do more clearly. What I have at the moment is 2 pages, the main page which displays all of the information and a 2nd page which queries the database and pulls out the user's profile. When the javascript variable inCallingNum changes, I need to send this to the user_data.php page and update the information to show the new person's profile.

Comment: `displaystatus()` is a javascript function?

Comment: You cannot set server-side variable from PHP in client-side JS.JavaScript is executed only after the PHP script already renders your page. You would need to make a new request (via AJAX) to provide the server with a value computed on client side with JavaScript.

Comment: Not really enough information to understand what you are trying to do. Where does the calling number come from? Could you post a better explanation of what is going on?

Comment: displaystatus() is a javascript function, but I don't know javascript very well at all so I don't know how it works. How would I send the javascript value using AJAX?

Comment: You can get variables from JS to PHP with XHR (directly) or a cookie (indirectly). Both can be triggered by JS.

Comment: From where is `inCallingNum` coming from? User input? Database? Nevermind. meouw already asked for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php is server-side code, javascript is client-side code. It is not possibile to do what you're asking, you have to set `$user_number` with a call to the server.

When you are working with javascript you have already had the response from the server, so you are working with the result of the server-side actions, you cannot change the source from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since JS is run after Apache processes the PHP page, this is not possible.

Answer (score -4):

you can try this,

```
<?php $user_number = inCallingNum ?>
```

where `inCallingNum` is your javascript variable.

Comment: Nnno, that's not at all how it works.