# Use array values from PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I want to perform javascript functions on a page after I retrieve some values from a local database. However once the PHP code is in my javascript the javascript function won't even run in the first place. If I separate the PHP code out and run the PHP code alone, it works fine, as well as the javascript code too. Here's my code:

```
<?
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3307", "username", "password") or die ("Error fetching value from database.");
mysql_select_db("ccmalumni");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT value FROM ccm_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 16") or die ("What da heck");
$states = db_result_array_values($result);
echo $states[0];
mysql_close();

function db_result_array_values($result) { 
for ($array = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); isset($row[1]) ? $array[$row[1]] = $row[0] : $array[] = $row[0]); 
return $array; }
?>

var present = <? echo json_encode($states); ?>;
```

Please, what am I doing wrong? You can see the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/ftFd2Ccf).

Thanks.

Comment: declare your vars between `<script>` & `</script>` tags

Comment: are you using a javascript console in your browser to debug this?  is it showing any parsing errors when loading the page?

Comment: also what is being echoed in the line `echo $states[0];`?  is it valid javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode` will  out put json string in the form that javascript can understand so basically fix like below;

```
var darr = <? echo json_encode($states); ?>;  //Already readable JSON
var present = darr ;
```

Comment: You can try to view source on browser and see what is printed out

Comment: Actually, that was a more recent modification, my original code simply had `var present = <? echo json_encode($states); ?>` (who wants to do extra coding). I solved the problem by viewing the source, I discovered all my PHP code was not being processed. The problem was because I started my code with `<?` instead of `<? php`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$.parseJSON() parses a string to javascript object. `var darr` is already an object , is not a string, and therefore should not be passed to `$.parseJSON()`

See [$.parseJSON() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from server to client, i think the best way is to do a ajax request.
Because you dont have to mix server with client side 
(makes your code more readable, easy to understand etc.)

here you get a short description how to do it with jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/415894/1067061

hope it helps, good luck!