# how to get element id of div and appendChild html to it

Tags: javascript

I want to get the ID of a `div` using JavaScript that runs inside that `div`.  I want to `appendChild()` html to that `div`.

eg:

```
<div id="randomnumber">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var htmlcontent = "abcdf";
//need the id of div holder
var thisDIVid= ?????;
// appendChild to this div
?????.appendChild(htmlcontent);
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where in the structure your div is placed you can access it like this:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
yourDiv = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('div')[number];
```

number is the place in the structure

Answer (score -2):

`document.getElementyById("yourDivId");` will find any div with an unique ID.

```
var div = document.getElementyById("yourDivId");
div.appendChild("yourContent");
```

Comment: thanks.. but the id of div created by other script which is random .. so i need get it from script running inside that div, the point is.. i need to use appendChild to write some code html in that div but can not do without knowing id of this div...

Comment: If you include your script the you can set id to somekind of a global variable.

Comment: the id created by php from server.. :(

Comment: Then search here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415868/get-variable-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: thanks.. but was thinking about that, but not work on my case :) only way is javascript detect id of div element which hold it.

Comment: Then use parentNode. 'myElem.parentNode;'

Comment: I can not make this work.. could you help.. thanks
<div id="random"><script type="text/javascript">alert(myElem.parentNode.id);</script></div>

Comment: You can find divs by className and then If you now where in your HTML structure it is paste the content there.