# PHP variable inside a js file

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to transfer an array between PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393479/best-way-to-transfer-an-array-between-php-and-javascript)

How do I put the value of a PHP variable inside a Javascript variable? 
This is what I have now in a js file:

```
test=<?php echo $country; ?>;
```

Comment: `var jsvariable = '<?php echo $phpvariable; ?>';` or `var jsvariable = <?php echo $phpvariable; ?>;` if it's an integer value

Comment: You have to tell the server to parse your file as PHP, and the client to parse it as JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to properly escape your variables before passing them to JavaScript. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) for this, as it escapes and encodes your values in a way suitable for using with JavaScript:

```js
test=<?php echo json_encode($country) ?>;
```

Never simply send the variable un-encoded, as it might break things, or, worse, if the value comes from untrusted sources, compromise your security.

Also, rename your file to `.php` instead of `.js` if you want to be able to insert dynamic PHP code inside it.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that the browser doesn't care what the serverside (PHP) code was. It only cares what the rendered code (Javascript and HTML) looks like.  So your PHP

```
test=<?php echo $country; ?>;
```

will come out something like this, presuming `$country` is a string:

```
test=USA
```

That is valid Javascript, but it doesn't set `test` to have the value `USA`.  It sets `test` to the value of the variable `USA`, which is almost certainly `undefined`.  You need to use quotation marks to make a Javascript string literal:

```
test="<?php echo $country; ?>";
```

This will be rendered as so:

```
test="USA";
```

and will do what you expect.

---

I see now that you've mentioned that the file is a js file.  I presumed above that it was a standard PHP-with-HTML file.  As it is, everything above is still valid.  However, serving a PHP script as Javascript is only slightly tricky.

First, name your file `filename.php` (or whatever other name you want).  This is by far the easiest way to get the webserver to know to parse it with PHP.  Then use the following instruction to let the browser know that the file is Javascript content:

```
header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
```

Put that at the very top of your file, before any content is sent to the browser.  You can then include PHP variables as you like.

Answer (score 2):

put your JS code inside a .php file and try like this:

```
<html>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
function echoSession(num) 
{ 
 window.document.newForm.mybox.value=num; 
 <?PHP echo $VAR ?> 
}
 </script>
</html>
```

The point is your file should be a PHP file to make server to parse it as php. if it is a .js file it will not work

Comment: You forgot the `</html>` tag. You should also probably give it a `<body>`.

Comment: Well this was a fast code snippet...those things are really obvious and everybody should know them :P

Comment: I forget things a lot of the time too. Just thought I'd point it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to make sure that you understand this, because I see a lot of beginners stumbling over the difference between server side scripting and client side scripting, javascript is a client side scripting language, while PHP is server side. If you understand this, you can basically skip this paragraph. When the user requests a page, such as mysite.com/whatever.php, the request gets sent to the server. Because the user requests the PHP file, the server knows that it should parse the file before sending it to the user. When parsing a file, the server starts n HTML mode, which means that all the text it reads is going directly to the user. From the moment php encounters a  or the end of the file. When the end of the file is reached, it sends the output to the user. This output may contain script tags in it's HTML. These peaces of javascript will be executed when they are red together with the HTML by the browser.

However, an external javascript file, doesn't need to have the .js extension, just like css. Therefore, you can also make a php file that outputs js, and do as one of the previous answers suggested, so to put this js code in a .php file:

```
var somevar = <?php echo $var; ?>;
```

as you can see, after the equals sign in the javascript, the php variable $var 's value will be printed. This value will therefore be assigned to the js variable  called somevar when the output is red by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to use markup within a Javascript file, you must either:

1) Modify your .htaccess file to include *.js as a valid extension for files to be processed through the PHP Engine. (Google around for this)

2) Change the Javascript file extension from *.js to *.php.

3) Declare variables which are set through PHP within the main PHP/HTML file, rather than the external Javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

There is the json_encode (http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) method to print php variables for javascript.

```
test = <?php echo json_encode($value) ?>
```

Works even if $value is an array, but in your case if it's a string, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I face often when dealing with js vs php. As my JS applications become more complex there is more and more a desire to keep all my JS in library files and keep my php as clean as possible. One solution I have started using is to do the following:

js file:

```
myNamespace.bootstrap = function( payload ){
  ... 
  // internally boot up all the modules that need 
  // the data, passing it where relavent
  module.load( payload );
}
```

php file:

```
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    myNamespace.bootstrap(<?= json_encode($payload_object); ?>);
  </script>
</body>
```

This gives you one data injection point for all your scripts with one line of js in your actual php. Should allow you to easy manage data dependencies in your javascript since you can namespace them in php.