# How to decode and encode a multidimensional array in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, decode

I need to encode a three dimensional array in javascript, send it to a php script and decode it there. The Problem is, javascript outputs array, just as one sequence of integers, you can't see the dimensions. I tried to convert the array to json but couldn't find figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array+javascript+php

Comment: Google "Javascript encode JSON" and "PHP decode JSON"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to transfer an array between PHP and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393479/best-way-to-transfer-an-array-between-php-and-javascript)

Comment: @Luke, use the inner power of php... http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're making an ajax call, say using $.post, jQuery will automatically encode the data before it hits the PHP script you called. The size, scope, and complexity of the object doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm sending the data via a hidden form and a submit button. what about that?

Comment: If you've gone through the trouble of using javascript for your form, you might as well, go full-on ajax anyway. Anyhow, there's no native jQuery method to encode json outside of the ajax methods. As @hoppa suggests google "Javascript encode JSON" and in PHP 5, it's json_decode.

Comment: JSON is supported from PHP 5.2, just to be accurate. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to serialize the array - JSON or something similar. It provides a format to convert objects and arrays to plain text and vice versa.