# how to put javascript variable in php echo

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add JavaScript variable to php echo

```
arr[i]='<?php echo $winner[javascript variable]; ?>';
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking is possible. Do you want some value calculated by JavaScript to be inserted into a PHP script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function/7016795#7016795

Comment: if anything, you can use ajax to send a javascript variable to the server, then return the rendered PHP. but that's probably not the workflow you're looking for, since i'm sure you're talking about rendering a page normally...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

1. PHP runs on the server and outputs some text.
2. The text is sent to the browser
3. The browser interprets the text as HTML / JavaScript / etc

The PHP has finished running by the time the JavaScript is executed.

If you want to pass data back you need to make a **new** HTTP request and run a PHP script from scratch.

Comment: I hava php array and I want to convert it to javascript array 

Is this possible ?

Comment: `var myJSArray = <?php echo json_encode($myPHPArray); ?>;`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393479/best-way-to-transfer-an-array-between-php-and-javascript

Comment: i'm sorry. but it can be.  you need to echo all the script including your php variables and then run javascript

Comment: @MFarooqi — Your two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: :D I mean to say "it is possible".. I said sorry for your "not possible" reason. and again  (i apology for poor english)

Comment: @MFarooqi — I understood what you were saying. You are still contradicting yourself. If [passing data from JS to PHP] is possible [without making a new HTTP request], then you don't have to do all the PHP stuff first.