# how to print a variable of javascript in php?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to put javascript variable in php echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853630/how-to-put-javascript-variable-in-php-echo)

I have JavaScript to get time and the code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date();

var H = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
if(H>11)
{
    var h = H-12;
    var a = 'PM';
}
else
{
    var h = H;
    var a = 'AM';
}

</script>
```

Now, I want to print the variables in PHP that used in JavaScript like,

```
<?php echo $h.$m; ?>
```

Is it possible?

if yes then help me.

Comment: Is the search broken for you?

Comment: PHP executes on the server-side.  JavaScript executes on the Client-side.  Research writing JavaScript values to your HTML.

Comment: You can't push client side js to PHP on the same page

Comment: dude, javascript runs in the browser and php runs in the server. Am i missing something?

Comment: Wow the same question was asked 20 minutes ago, lazy, lazy, lazy

Answer (score 1):

Javascipt runs on the client, php runs on the server... 
If you just want to print the var in the browser

```
var varName = "varValue";
document.write(varName);
```

if you need to send the javascript var to php, you need to send it to the server with jquery or javscript and then return the data...

```
$.post("yourFile.php", { varName: "varValue" },
function(data) {
   //print the data coming from yourFile.php
   document.write(data);
```

});

if you only need to send the var to the server

```
 $.post("yourFile.php", { hour: "hour", min: "min", sec:"sec" } );
```

Comment: I want to insert the time in database. that's why I want it to store in a variable in php.

Comment: ok, just use     $.post("yourFile.php", { hour: "hour", min: "min", sec:"sec" } ); then on php use $_POST['hour'] to retrieve the value

Comment: vote up if you solve the problem ;-)