# How to echo a JS-variable in php and then append or include php file to HTML object?

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

Hi stackoverflow people,

I'm making a variable code where you can easily put another file-code in between e.g. a `div`. I'm wondering if you can include a PHP-file via JavaScript, with JS variables. I can do it via PHP but can I include a file with JS?

HTML:

```
<div id="someId">THE INCLUDE HERE</div>
```

JS:

```
var tag_id = 'someId'; //comes form DB
var url = 'data/includes/code.php'; // comes from DB

$('#' + tag_id).html('<?php include("' + url + '"); ?>');
```

As you can see, `tag_id` is the id of a object and the url is not static but comes from the DB.

---

I've read and tried those (but didn't work..):

- [send javaScript variable to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable)
- [how to print a variable of javascript in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157805/how-to-print-a-variable-of-javascript-in-php)

Maybe I have to think out of my box, can you guys help me?

(Sorry for bad English...)

Comment: just so you know, this won't work because php is executed before javascript runs, and php won't run again until the next page load.

Comment: yes, but can js not include a file or something?

Comment: you can use AJAX to get the html output of a page and display that, but you wont be able to include php variables from that file into your current file.

Comment: You can't do that. You need to look into Ajax.

Comment: Wait, i've found something else: `$('#' + tag_id).load(url)` , this works!

Comment: `$('#' + tag_id).load(url)` is a form of ajax which is why it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant include a php page through a JS variable, however you could use AJAX to retrieve the HTML contents and place it in a DOM like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "data/includes/code.php",
    success: function(result) {
        $('#' + tag_id).html(result);
    }
});
```

This can be simplified to:

```
$('#' + tag_id).load(url);
```

Comment: brilliant this works much better!! Thanks @Daniel McAssey