# Why does document.write + echo not work?

Tags: php, javascript, document.write

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to put javascript variable in php echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853630/how-to-put-javascript-variable-in-php-echo)

I have a problem with PHP. I want to use a PHP variable in JavaScript. However, it does not work! `$doccontent` is displayed just once! Here is `Test.php` (the page parameter is given, e.g. `Test.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <?php
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($page);
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $contentnode = $doc->getElementById('content');
        $doccontent = new DOMDocument();
        $doccontent->appendChild($doccontent->importNode($contentnode, true));
        $doccontent = $doccontent->saveHTML();
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $doccontent;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("<?php echo $doccontent;?>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is `Test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hey</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Edit.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="admin"><a href="Edit.php?page=Edit.html">Edit</a></button>
        <h1>Automatica</h1>
        <div id="content">
            <h2>Header 1.1</h2>
            <p>Test</p>
            <h3>Header 1.1.1</h3>
            <p>Test</p>
            <h3>Header 1.1.2</h3>
            <p>Test</p>
            <p>Test</p>
            <h4>Header 2.0.0.1</h4>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$doccontent;` has a value? If so, is it text? Does it contain " (double quotes)? If so it is probably breaking your `document.write`

Comment: Can you perhaps let us know WHY you would want to go through these hoops to load an HTML page into the current page?

Comment: @hakre: it's actually the opposite

Comment: @mplungjan: I need to edit that page

Comment: @Agantacroxi: Yes, there are tons of exact duplicates. I just picked one Quentin was involved in, so you get an additional note of same quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$doccontent` almost certainly contains both `"` characters and new lines, either of which will break a JS string literal delimited by `"` characters.

The PHP `json_encode` function will, given a string as input, output a JS string literal. You could use that instead of echoing the raw data. (Remember not to add extra `"` characters around the generated string literal).

Comment: is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Wow, great! This solved my question. That was quick! :)

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes though to give you the best answer