# How to concatenate PHP variable with JavaScript Variable? Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript

Java Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
         var  seatNo = 2;                                                       
         str.push('<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + '<?php echo $thisPacket["seat"]; ?>'</a>');
         }); 
</script>
```

I want to concatenate between `$thisPacket["seat"]` with java Script variable `seatNo.`
Just like php concate. example: `$i = 1; $thisPacket["seat".$i]`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put javascript variable in php echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853630/how-to-put-javascript-variable-in-php-echo) or [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php) or of you meant otherwise echoing PHP into jS see [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines?rq=1)

Comment: This is a common misconception for novices because Javascript code and PHP code can co-exist in the same file. However, PHP executes _before_ HTML and Javascript is sent to the browser. Therefore you can't use Javascript variables in a PHP variable. You _can_ use the result of PHP variables in Javascript variables however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to concatenate between $thisPacket["seat"] with java Script
>   variable seatNo. Just like php concate. example: $i = 1;
>   $thisPacket["seat".$i];

No, this won't work because the PHP code runs on the server, and the javascript variable `seatNo` is not available until the javascript code executes on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to serialize `$thisPacket` as a JSON object and send that to the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var thePacket = <?=json_encode($thisPacket);?>;
        $(function () {
        var  seatNo = 2;                                                       
            str.push('<a title="' + seatNo + '">' + thePacket['seat'+seatNo] + '</a>');
         }); 
</script>
```

But im guessing that you should really reconsider your current design.

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible, because JavaScript is a client-side language and will be executed after that all PHP commands was executed in the server and the page completely rendered. But PHP is a server-side language and is execued before any JavaScript code is interpreted.

Comment: So displaying HTML is also not possible, because HTML is client-side, and PHP server-side

Comment: @vladkras: No, The main duty of PHP is `HTML Rendering` and `HTTP Handling`, So PHP can manipulate html when it is rendering a page

Comment: the main duty is to be _general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development_ you can render JS as well and even generate it on fly

Comment: @vladkras: At this step you're right, But i think you did not read my answer carefully, My mean in this answer is **Access to content of JS variables is impossible while PHP is rendering**, Okay?

Comment: I get what you're saying. I think @vladkras had a problem with _how_ you said it. :)

Answer (score 0):

take you php variable and assign it to javascript variable than concatenate them.

```
var phpVar = '<?php echo $thisPacket["seat"]; ?>';
var seatNo =  2;
var conVar = seatNo + phpVar;
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var  seatNo = 2;                                                       
            str.push('<a title="' + seatNo + '"><?php echo $thisPacket["seat"]; ?></a>');
         }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but my problem is, I want to concatenate between $thisPacket["seat"] with java Script variable seatNo.
Just like php concate. example: $i = 1; $thisPacket["seat".$i];

Comment: You only can concatenate a javascript variable with a php variable, but in the other direction it is impossible.