# Get text value using jQuery and pass variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I'm working on a profile page that auto-populates email field, would like to get text value and then use it as variable on PHP.

To get the text value, using jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var str = jQuery(".user_email").text();
});
```

Is there a way to echo variable "str"? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put javascript variable in php echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853630/how-to-put-javascript-variable-in-php-echo)

Comment: If you want to use it on the same page, it's not possible. PHP loads on the server before it goes to the user, jQuery/javascript renders after in the browser. If you want to do something with it, you'll need to submit it to a PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on the same page since php is executed on the server while javascript runs from the browser. However, where is the auto populate value coming from ?
If it is from a DB or an external API resouce (e.g in json or xml) then you can directly assign that to a php variable without passing it through javascript

Answer (score -1):

log it to the browser javascript console

console.log('str', str);

how to display the console varys amongst browsers

**EDIT**  ok... apparently this wasn't what the OP wanted at all..
probably wants to jQuery.ajax('/url', {str:str});  to send the value to the server.

My question:  if these values are on the page..  where did they come from... did they not originate server-side/php ?

Comment: That is not what OP is asking.

Comment: @noob:  he asked "how to echo str"

Comment: Definitely no on console. OP mentioned that he wishes to _use it as variable on PHP_, for that purpose he wants to test it out by using `echo`. On a side note: **I didn't down voted your answer.**

Comment: OK.. is it kosher to remove an answer?

Comment: Yes, it is if your answer is not contributing anything to the solution. Besides when a question is marked as duplicate a solution is probably present so there is no point in giving out same answer.