# Get PHP data into Javascript Array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to transfer an array between PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393479/best-way-to-transfer-an-array-between-php-and-javascript)

I am trying to return a series of arrays from PHP to javascript using AJAX.

I have tried pre-formatting the email addresses as a JSON object and returning that to my JS script and then parsing it as JSON but no luck.

I have a main array called emails, and I want these arrays returned from PHP and to be converted to a JS array, I have tried:

```
emails = $.makeArray($.parseJSON(email)) ;
```

But with no luck.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: how are you saving those arrays?

Comment: The "related" column (which *was* shown to you when you entered your question title) has all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `JSON_encode` to pass the array directly from PHP to a Javascript variable:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        array("foo" => "bar")
    );
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myarray = <?php echo JSON_encode($my_array); ?>;
    alert(myarray[0].foo);
</script>
```